# Java algorithm to slice a list

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to slice a list (call this input list & it contains Java double data type elements) in multiple parts (sub lists). The size of the sub lists can be unequal by a small number.  Each part (sub list) serves as an input to another program.  The size of the input list is a variable with a maximum size of 10,000 i.e. it can be as small as 1 or 2 or 3 and as big as 100 or 10000 or any number under 10000.

What is the best way to slice such a list into multiple parts? I have been considering  the 3h+1 distribution by Donald Knuth in designing gaps for shell sort. However, I'm not sure whether it would be appropriate. Appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: What for do you want to slice the list?

Comment: It really depends on the condition you want to slice

Comment: @java_pill - are you just planning to slice it up based on # of records? or some criteria in the data itself?  What determines how to split the list up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the answer the optimal value of M,

Assume there is some cost function C associated with processing a list of size M.

Then you want to minimize the function

TotalCost = M * C(N/M) + overhead

where overhead is the cost of splitting up the list.

I think for most applications there wouldn't be much difference for different values of M, so there is no point in splitting it up.

The situation where it would be useful is if you have multiple processors so and you can hand off the sublists to a different processor. In this case, the cost function would be more like

TotalCost = C(N/M) + overhead     if M < number of processors

so you should choose M to be close to but less than the number of processors.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding this question, this seeems easy.

Given a list of size N, to create M sublists, where M < N,

1. create M-1 lists of size K = N/M
   (rounding down)
2. create a list of
   size M - (M - 1) * K

Then

1. copy the first K elements to the
   first list
2. copy the next K elements to the
   second list,
3. and so on,
4. finally copy the last M - (M - 1) * K to the
   last list.

Comment: What would be the optimal value for M? given that N varies. Or how do you determine the value of M?

Comment: Optimal value for M depends on the application characteristics. Is it cheaper to process a N lists of size N/M vs a single list of size N? If so, by what factor?